# How do I know if a cell returns a null value while reading an Excel Sheet?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading values from some specific cells in an excel sheet. Those cells generally contain String but sometimes they may be blank (thus may return a blank or a null). I am using the following code to get the cell data:

```
Cell cellValue = row.getCell(10, Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
List.add(cellValue.getStringCellValue());
```

However, when I run this code I get a `NullPointerException`. Can anybody point out what is wrong and should be added?

Note: I am deliberately using `Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK` and not `MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK` because using the latter was giving me an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to test the `cellValue` if it is not null, since using `Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK` will return `null` in cases where you are trying to access a missing cell.

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because the 10-th column on a specified row is missing.

If you need to handle differently the missing vs. blank cases you can use the following:

```
Cell cellValue = row.getCell(10, Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
if (cellValue == null)
    List.add("CELL NOT FOUND");
else if("".equals(cellValue.getStringCellValue().trim()))
    List.add("MISSING CONTENT");
else 
    List.add(cellValue.getStringCellValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

@dan - Thanks for your reply. That indeed helped. I modified my code as follows and I am not getting that exception now:

```
Cell cellValue = row.getCell(10, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
if(cellValue.getStringCellValue().equals("")){
    List.add("NOT FOUND");
}
else {
    List.add(cellValue.getStringCellValue());
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. But note that now you are handling the empty cells and the missing ones the same. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

hey there ,
             why cant you add the null pointer check like

```
if(null!=cellValue)

    {

    List.add(cellValue.getStringCellValue());
}
```

hope this helps if the cell value is null then you dont add the cell value to your list.